# Help identify component

Tags: resistors

I am trying to fix a hair straightener and I found what appears to be burnt resistors. 
They are surface mount but they don't look like surface mount. They look like a mini version of your regular metal film resistors. However as far as I can tell they are 51 Ohm (Green, Brown, Black, Gold), and used in mains voltage (240V). So I am thinking they are high wattage variety of some sort. My local Jaycar didn't have a clue. Can someone here help me source this component or a substitute? [image: Resistor]

(It's about a centimetre long)

Comment: These are known as MELF components.  Both resistors and diodes are available in the MELF package.

Comment: I love these, they are so cute. You don't want to tip the board too much before the solder phase though. :)

Comment: Your Jaycar didn't have a clue? Wow they should at least identified that it was a MELF package, because they supply MELF diodes... Only.

Comment: Yeah the guy was clueless. I don't expect much from them any more though. Sourced them on Mouser but they are asking $28 for shipping for 2 resistors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look like MELF resistors, presumably of a fusible/flameproof metal film type.  They're not the easiest to find (through-hole is much more popular for them, and MELF also expands to Many End up Lying on the Floor -- it's a cylindrical package if you haven't already noticed, so it likes to roll away when you're trying to handle it. ;).  I'd try the major catalog distributors in your area -- they'll at least know what a MELF package is.  Power ratings for these, by the way, are on the same order as their through hole counterparts -- namely 1-2W.

Comment: Thanks! Could I substitute a normal surface mount resistor in its place?

Comment: Likely not -- the circuit is probably counting on it to fail quietly to an open state instead of into a poof of smoke.

Comment: In my case the latter happened. 2 burnt resistors and a completely disintegrated cap.